# The type namespace name Form1 could not be found

Tags: c#

Hello i am having trouble with this code I need to fix one error "The type namespace name Form1 could not be found" any help will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using PS3Lib;

namespace xpartygo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PS3API PS3 = new PS3API();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PS3.ConnectTarget();
                PS3.AttachProcess();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
                button3.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                PS3.Extension.WriteUInt32(0x3DBD54, 0x480000D8); // Disable Cheat Protection
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect!");
            }
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PS3.ChangeAPI(SelectAPI.TargetManager);
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PS3.ChangeAPI(SelectAPI.ControlConsole);
        }

        public void Cbuf_AddText(string text)
        {
            PS3.Extension.WriteString(0x10075000, text); // Write Command Input
            PS3.SetMemory(0x37F80, new byte[] { 0xF8, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x91, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x02, 0xA6, 0xF8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x38, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x80, 0x10, 0x07, 0x30, 0x84, 0x50, 0x00, 0x48, 0x2D, 0xBC, 0x81, 0xE8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x03, 0xA6, 0x38, 0x21, 0x00, 0x70, 0x4E, 0x80, 0x00, 0x20 }); // Cbuf_AddText RPC
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            PS3.SetMemory(0x37F80, new byte[] { 0xF8, 0x21, 0xFE, 0xD1, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x02, 0xA6, 0xF8, 0x01, 0x01, 0x40, 0xDB, 0x21, 0x00, 0xF8, 0xDB, 0x41, 0x01, 0x00, 0xDB, 0x61, 0x01, 0x08, 0xDB, 0x81, 0x01, 0x10, 0xDB, 0xA1, 0x01, 0x18, 0xDB, 0xC1, 0x01, 0x20, 0xDB, 0xE1, 0x01, 0x28, 0xFB, 0xE1, 0x00, 0xF0 }); // Restore CG_DrawFPS Function
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cbuf_AddText("party_connectToOthers 0;partyMigrate_disabled 1;party_mergingEnabled 0;xpartygo");
            MessageBox.Show("Has been executed!", "xpartygo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cbuf_AddText("reset party_connectToOthers;partyMigrate_disabled;party_mergingEnabled");
            MessageBox.Show("Has been executed!", "Dvar Reset", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is the namespace:

[image]

Comment: please post your code here.

Comment: Edited, doesn't come out that well

Comment: i dont see where this code would be failing with that compile error.

Comment: The error points me to this line: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line you mentioned, `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());` is in a file in a different namespace to `xpartygo`, you'll need to edit it to `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new xpartygo.Form1());` to sort the namespaces.

Alternatively, place the file with the above line into the same namespace.

In future, pasting the **exact** error message as output from the compiler, along with any code it references, makes life a lot easier for people wanting to help - which makes life easier for you :-)

Just in case it's a lack of understanding of namespaces that's the issue, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0d941h9d.aspx) for more info.

Edit in response to comment:
Cool, we all start somewhere - class A can only "see" class B if they're either in the same namespace, or class A  has a `using` statement referencing this namespace that class B lives in.

It's like a folder structure, you can only see files/`classes` in the directory/`namespace` you're currently in, unless you look up/`using` another folder/`namespace`.

A class' namespace is defined by the `namespace foo { ... }` block it's inside. The link above should explain all this in more detail than I can.

Your problem is likely that you have two classes in different namespaces, and one's trying to access the other. Unless you deal with this properly, by "looking up" the appropriate namespace, you'll get the compilation error you saw.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to coding so I don't know exactly what I'm doing :(

Comment: Nevermind this site doesn't let me post codes I'll just leave it for a while since I have no idea what I'm doing, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: The folder/file analogy is just an analogy - the directory structure should match the namespace structure, but it won't necessarily. You need to look for the `namespace` of each of the classes in order to resolve this, not the directory path.